# When does queryForTable get called in the view controller lifecycle in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to customize the functionality of PFQueryTableViewController and pull in some information before queryForTable gets called so I can use this information in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't know or worry about it, and doing so means you're taking the wrong approach. You're using a 3rd party piece of code so you shouldn't rely on anything undocumented or private.

So, gather your required information and then push the controller / create the table view. In this way you guarantee that things will work correctly and you can specifically update the user with progress / status.

Comment: Yes, but I need to continuously update this data when queryForTable is called. It's not just a one time thing. So, I think it does matter for my case!

Comment: In any case I figured it out, so no need to respond. Thanks :).

Comment: Hi @user3137679, could you explain your solution? I need to execute a first query and use the returned object in queryForTable()… Thank you in advance!